# git-svn create svn branch from svn branch

Tags: branch, git-svn

With git-svn If I have cloned svn repository with all trunk, branches and tags, how do I create a new svn branch out of a svn branch?

I know I can create a new branch from trunk (master) with git svn branch, but how do I handle this from a branch?

SHould I first create a local tracking branch from the branch, and out of it invoke git svn branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using a local tracking branch, and create branch from it:

```
git checkout master
git branch --track localToBeCloned BranchToBeCloned
git checkout localToBeCloned
git svn branch NewClone -m "new branch created"
git branch --track localNewClone NewClone
git checkout localNewClone
```